# How to set the type to a ref object, which can be assignable to all inherited classes with same root class

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an inheritance hierarchy like below:

[image: class hierarchy]

In another component (let call it MyClass), I'm using the components `B` and `D` (or any of concrete classes `E, F, G, H`) like below:

```
abstract class MyClass {

    protected componentRef: React.RefObject</* This is where I'm stuck */> = React.createRef();

    public render() {
        const Component = flag ? B : D;
        return (
          <Component
            {...props}
            ref={this.componentRef}
          />
        );
    }
}
```

As I'm using typescript in my project I get a type error `TS2322` because of the incompatibility between the `ref` prop and `this.componentRef`. I need to set ref prop to access `F()` method of the class `A` in elsewhere.

My problem is I don't know how I must define the type of `componentRef` member in the class `MyClass`.

I tried to solve the problem by setting `componentRef` type like below,

```
protected componentRef: React.RefObject<? extends A> = React.createRef();
```

but no success. To be honest, I don't familiar with the typescript type definition schemes.
Also, I don't prefer below solution.

```
abstract class MyClass<ComponentType extends A> {
  protected componentRef: React.RefObject<ComponentType> = React.createRef();
}
```

and setting the type to `any`.

Is there any chance to exists any other solution similar to what I tried to do? (like define a generic type using `type` keyword)